# Entity with data from two tables

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

Can I create an entity that will retrieve data from 2 (or more) tables?

I would like to have tables:

```
user: id, name, password
user_address: idUser, street, city
```

And UserEntity with:

```
int: id
String: name, password, street, city
```

When using only one table, I have got:

UserEntity:

```
@Entity
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "user")
    private String user;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    //+ getter + setters
}
```

and a method for loading users from DB with code:

```
String queryString = "FROM UserEntity WHERE user = :user AND password = :password";
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
query.setString("user", userForm.getUser());
query.setString("password", userForm.getPassword());
UserEntity userEntity = (UserEntity) query.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: It's possible, but why would you do that instead of storing everything in one table?

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is because - not every user will have got address. So I thing, better is store it in two tables.

Comment: If so, shouldn't the User have an OneToOne association with another Address entity? If you store every field of the address directly in the User entity, the natural mapping is to store the fields in the user table.

Comment: Quick answer - yes you can (use @SecondaryTable annotation). Longer answer - are you restricting a user to have only one address? You didn't include enough information on your data definition to determine whether your DB restricts this relationship to one-to-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But I would suggest one java class for each table. `User` and `Address` and then you want to use the join [`@JoinColumn`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier) annotation to specify the column that tables are joined by.

If you do not want two separate classes you can use a ResultTransformer.